# Perform Laravel Eloquent 'select' statement meeting conditions in multiple related tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a blog database schema with tables `posts`, `categories` and a few more. For every record in `posts` table there is a column `post_category` containing the id of a record in `categories` table. Also there are flag fields `post_active`, respectively `cat_active` (for `categories` table) indicating if the post/category is available to be read or not (if 1 - active, if 0 - inactive).

For example:

Table "posts":

```
+---------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+
| post_id | post_title |  post_content  | post_category | post_active |
+---------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+
|    1    | Lorem..... | ipsum dolor... |  1            | 1           |
+---------+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------+
```

Table "categories":

```
+--------+----------+------------+
| cat_id | cat_name | cat_active |
+--------+----------+------------+
| 1      | Category |  1         |
+--------+----------+------------+
```

Currently, I'm using Eloquent's `where()` clause to select all active posts from `posts` table:

```
$posts = Post::where('post_active', '=', 1)->get();
```

But there might be a situation in which a post is active (`posts.post_active = 1`), but the whole category is not (`categories.cat_active = 0`). How can I select all active posts, which belong to an active category with Eloquent? Vanilla SQL statement also works, it can easily be converted to Eloquent.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `whereHas` to do what you want.

**Post Model**

```
class Post ...
...
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'post_category', 'cat_id');
    }
```

Then you can do

```
$posts = Post::where('post_active', '=', 1)
             ->whereHas('categories', function($q) {
                 $q->where('cat_active','=',1)
             })
             ->get();
```

That will filter only the posts that have a active category.

Answer (score 0):

**Category.php**

```
class Category {
    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'post_category', 'cat_id')->active();
    }
    public function scopeActive() {
        return $query->where('cat_active', 1);
    }
}
```

**Post.php**

```
class Post {
    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'post_category', 'cat_id')->active()
    }

    public function scopeActive() {
        return $query->where('post_active', 1);
    }
}
```

Your query will be:

```
$categories = Category::active()->with('posts')->get();
```

Or

```
$posts = Post::active()->has('category')->get();
```